# how to insert and display the enter key or new line from codeigniter to database using textarea

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using a textarea in my html and I also want to store my inputted word on my database by using codeigniter. for example if i entered the word "Hello" and the next line is "World"

like

```
Hello
World
```

view

```
<textarea name=text></textarea>
```

and before passing it to the controller this is my javascript

```
function add_work_experience()
{
var P1 = document.getElementById('company');
var P2 = document.getElementById('job_title');
var P3 = document.getElementById('text');
var P4 = document.getElementById('date');
var P5 = document.getElementById('description');


if (P1.value != "" && P2.value != "" && P3.value != "" && P4.value != "" && P5.value != "")
{
    var data = P1.value + "|" + P2.value + "|" + P3.value
    P1.value = "";
    P2.value = "";
    P3.value = "";
    swoosh(data, path+'swoosh_employee/swoosh_work_experience', 'workexperiencedv');

}
```

controller,, let's say that the variable $P3 is the textarea

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
    $data = $_GET['h'];
    list($P1,$P2,$P3) = explode("|", $data);
    $this->emp->add_word($P1, $P2, $P3);
```

model

```
public function add_word($text)
{
$data = array ('text' => $text);      

$this->db->insert('word', $data);
}
```

and by displaying it

```
<?php echo nl2br($text);?>
```

but it is not working. Is there something that i will do on my mysql server? or in my codeigniter? or in my php? help. i dont know what to do.

Comment: I suppose your view should have <textarea> and not <input>

Answer (score 3):

Try using [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert the new lines from the textarea into br tags:

```
$text = nl2br($this->input->post('text'));
```

Comment: oh im sorry. i'll add another code. because i forgot that im using a 
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
        $data = $_GET['h'];
list($P2, $P3, $P4) = explode("|", $data);